# Azure AD Group Claims from a powershell client

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use Azure AD group claims to check if a user is a member of a group before authenticating to a REST endpoint. I started by cloning this project: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims. However, there are two small differences.

1) I exposed a web API REST endpoint that calls GetGroups with the user token

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
ClaimHelper.GetGroups(identity)
```

2) I am authenticating with a powershell client rather than a browser. Here is how the client gets the token:

```
 #This function gets an azureADToken for our app
 function Get-AzureADToken2 {

    Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"

    $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com"
    $authContext = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext -ArgumentList ($authority);

    $appIdURI = "https://mysite.azurewebsites.net"
    $clientId = "6528ed9d9-1708-4b1b-851b-f773fa32f477"
    $redirectURI = "https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/api"

    #$platparam = new-object -TypeName Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters -ArgumentList ( [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]::Auto)
    $platparam = new-object -TypeName Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters -ArgumentList ( [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]::Always)



    $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($appIdURI, $clientId, $redirectURI,$platparam);
}
```

When the client is a browser, everything works as intended, and the call to getgroups lists the appropriate groups. However, when called with a powershell client, it throws an exception here (assuming the token isn’t cached from an earlier browser session, in which case there is no exception):

```
AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(ConfigHelper.GraphResourceId, credential,
     new UserIdentifier(claimsIdentity.FindFirst(Globals.ObjectIdClaimType).Value, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

{"Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken"}
```

When debugging and manually inspecting, the claim received from the browser and PS client seem nearly identical. I turned on ADAL diagnostics, but it had nothing useful. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause for this issue is that there is no access token in the cache of your web API. The code sample is using OWIN Open ID connection component to interact with Azure AD and it will acquire the access token after user login(check the code [Startup.Auth.cs#L39](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/blob/master/WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L39)) . After that it can use the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method to acquire the token silently from cache.

In your scenario, you can use **on-behalf-of flow** to acquire the access token for Azure AD Graph using the access token for your web API. More detail about this flow, you can refer link below:

[Calling a downstream web API from a web API using Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/)

Comment: One modification I had already had in Startup.auth.cs was adding a new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions. I modified it further to now be identical to this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/8afb3e6a648d8e7246685bf6747d009006c761b8/TodoListService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs, but I'm still getting the same error. Are there any other obvious differences between the groupclaims and downstream project that would also need to be modified?

Comment: The code you mentioned above is only used to protect the web API via verify the token from the request. This is not relative to get the token. To fix this issue, you are not able to use the code `authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync`.

Comment: You need to use the on-behalf-of flow to get the access token by the **user assertion**. Please check the code in the [TodoListController.cs#L153](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/8afb3e6a648d8e7246685bf6747d009006c761b8/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L153) which acquire the access token for the graph resource.

Comment: Thank you! This is the piece I was missing, in conjuncture with the startup piece (I believe I tried both separately while debugging).